# Embedding the xml file with the resource file and ship it with exe and also parse the xml file

Tags: xml, winapi, visual-c++

I need to read the xml file, parse it and extract the data.I do not want to add this XML file as separate file to the package. This can be done by embedding  the xml file with the resource file and ship it with exe.

Is it feasible to add xml file in this way and parse the content of xml? Any sample code(VC++) or weblink or any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your question? Yes, it is possible to embed **any** data as a (custom) resource in a module (as long as size constraints are met). Yes, it is possible to read a resource at runtime. Yes, it is possible to parse XML, using any XML parser (e.g. [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx)). So, really, what is your question? And please don't ask for offsite links, as this will provoke having your question closed.